# Displaying contents of database in listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, sqlite, android-listview

I've data in my Database which i intend to display to the user using a list view.. This is the function i wrote to display the contents

```
public class List_View extends ListActivity {

ListView lv; 

Databasehelp db = new Databasehelp(this);

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.displayitems);

     List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

     lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);


     Cursor cursor = db.getAllTable1(); cursor.moveToFirst();
     //startManagingCursor(cursor);

     lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.displayitems, items));
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

       ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
               R.layout.list_example_entry, cursor,
               new String[] {"name"},
               new int[] {R.id.name_entry});
       setListAdapter(adapter); 
          }             
     }
```

The layouts are displayitems.xml which contains a list view with the id "list" and list_example_entry.xml which contains a textview inside a linear layout with the id name_entry

displayitems.xml

```
 <ListView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
```

list_example_entry

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_entry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="28dip" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Can any one of you help me with this problem?

Comment: Why are you setting your adapter twice?
Your on the right track using the CursorAdapter, however, I'm not really sure what your trying to accomplish with the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: extend your class with Activity...and read [it](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: @Anand I can't use setListAdapter if i just extend with Activity

Comment: Ya i realized its SimpleCursorAdapter and changed it as below.. But if i check my log cat its giving the following error ** Caused by : java.lang . RuntimeException : Your container must have a listview whose attribute is 'android.R.id.list' **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call a cursor and then try to set an array adapter.  And then a cursor adapter...

Get rid of the ArrayAdapter call, it's not necessary.  You also do not need to call `moveToFirst()` when you are feeding the cursor into an adapter, the adapter takes care of that.

It should look like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
{ 
    super.onCreate(icicle); 
    setContentView(R.layout.displayitems); 

    Cursor cursor = db.getAllTable1();
    startManagingCursor(cursor); 

    SimpleCusrorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
           R.layout.list_example_entry, cursor, 
           new String[] {"name"}, 
           new int[] {R.id.name_entry}); 
    setListAdapter(adapter);  
 }
```

**EDIT**

The error means exactly what it says.  When you are using a ListActivity, it expects that your list will have the id `@id/android:list`.  So change your ListView xml to look like this:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent">  
</ListView>
```

If your last question in your comment is related to why you do not have to do a `findViewById`, that is becasue you are using a ListActivity, and it makes certain assumptions.  The main one being that there is one ListView in your layout and that it has the specific id mentioned above (which is why you got that error).  Since there is only the one and it knows what the id is, there is no need to call it out specifically.

Comment: Ya i realized its SimpleCursorAdapter and changed it as above.. But if i check my log cat its giving the following error
** Caused by : java.lang . RuntimeException : Your container must have a listview whose attribute is 'android.R.id.list' **
And also pls let know how is the above code confining the text view in list_example_entry to list view in displayitems?

Comment: That's because you never get an instance of your db handler (or open your database).  You have to do both before you try to pull a cursor.  It usually looks something like `yourDBHelper mDbHelper = new yourDBHelper(this);` followed by `mDbHelper.open();`.  If you have more issues on this you should post a new question.